# Angular : Activate checkbox on some conditions throws ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular

I currently implement angular project which needs a term and conditions agreement. So I have created a scrollable div of 300 px in which I load the content from the database. We want to force the user to read all T&C before activating the checkbox.

It's working well when T&C are heavy. When T&C are light, the scrollable function is not called. So I want to initialize the disabled state of the checkbox at the end of the loading but angular throws `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`.

Here is the stackblitz of my project : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b9p6rx

I tried many solutions :

- replace the `*ngIf` by `[hidden]`
- use a fonction to evaluate the state
- check in the `afterViewContentInit`
- Use a setter on the `div` content

I want to avoid the `setTimeout` call to evaluate the state.

What solutions do you see ?

Is there a better way to implement this function ?

Thanks in advance.

***app.component.html***

```
    <div class="content-box" *ngIf="isNotUpToDateCGU">
    <h1>Terms and conditions</h1>
    <span>
        <i>{{agreementHeader1}}</i>
    </span>
    <br>
    <div #cguContainer id="content" class="cgu-content" (scroll)="checkReading()" [innerHTML]="cguContent"></div>
    <div class="text-right">
        <span>I accept the terms and conditions</span>
        <p-checkbox [(ngModel)]="areCGUAccepted" binary="true" [disabled]="!hasContentBeenRead"></p-checkbox>
    </div>
    <div class="text-right cgu-buttons">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mx-2" >Annuler</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mx-2" [disabled]="!areCGUAccepted">Valider</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

***app.component.ts***

```
export class AppComponent  {
  public agreementHeader1: string;
    public cguContent: string;
    public hasContentBeenRead: boolean = false;
    public areCGUAccepted: boolean = false;
    public isNotUpToDateCGU: boolean  = false;

    private cguContainerRef: ElementRef;
    @ViewChild('cguContainer') set controlElRef(elementRef: ElementRef) {
      if (elementRef) {
        this.cguContainerRef = elementRef;
        this.checkReading();
      }
    }

    constructor(
        private confService: ConfigurationService,
    ) { }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
      this.confService.getConfiguration('./terms.json')
            .subscribe(result => {

                this.agreementHeader1 = 'You have to read all terms and conditions to accept them';

                // !!!!!!! invert the two lines to test with big terms
                // this.cguContent = result.bigTerms;
                this.cguContent = result.littleTerms;

                this.isNotUpToDateCGU = true; // load template
            });
    }

    public checkReading(): void {

        let element = this.cguContainerRef.nativeElement;

        // height of the div in css => height: 300px
        if (element.scrollHeight - element.scrollTop < 301) {
            this.hasContentBeenRead = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will only happen when app in dev mode. In your case this happen because after you set `this.isNotUpToDateCGU = true;` there is no new round of change detection happen until it might be triggered in future time. Therefore trigger change detection manually after your set `this.isNotUpToDateCGU = true;`

First import [`ChangeDetectorRef`](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef)

```js
import { ChangeDetectorRef  } from '@angular/core';
```

Then use it like below

```js
constructor(
    private confService: ConfigurationService,
    private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef
) { }

public ngOnInit(): void {
  this.confService.getConfiguration('./terms.json')
        .subscribe(result => {

            this.agreementHeader1 = 'You have to read all terms and conditions to accept them';

            // !!!!!!! invert the two lines to test with big terms
            // this.cguContent = result.bigTerms;
            this.cguContent = result.littleTerms;

            this.isNotUpToDateCGU = true; // load template
            this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();

        });
}
```

<kbd>[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xsdsr4?file=src/app/app.component.ts)</kbd>

Hope this will help to you!